# Failure when trying to install any snap

Tags: snap

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
sudo snap install core
```

but I get an error message:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "core" (1689) ([start snap-core-1689.mount] failed with exit 
status 6: Failed to issue method call: Unit systemd-fsck@dev-disk-
by\x2duuid-60797469\x2d195d\x2d415b\x2d8bfd\x2d4f048b15ec67.service failed 
to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status 
systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-
60797469\x2d195d\x2d415b\x2d8bfd\x2d4f048b15ec67.service' for details.
)
```

Results from uname -a:

```
 4.4.0-59-generic #80~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 18:02:02 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and systemctl status

```
Failed to issue method call: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties' on object at path /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/systemd_2dfsck_40dev_2ddisk_2dbyx2duuid_2d60797469x2d195dx2d415bx2d8bfdx2d4f048b15ec67_2eservice
```

and snap --version

```
snap    2.25~14.04
snapd   2.25~14.04
series  16
ubuntu  14.04
kernel  4.4.0-59-generic
```

I'm running in a VM so possibly that might have something to do with it

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling `snap`

Answer (score 0):

make a fake service to work around the error:

```
sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by...service
sudo systemctl enable systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by...service
```